# css3 transitions for before content on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

Hi everyone and sorry for my english, the title doesn't seem quite obvious. Here is what i'm trying to do. I have a navigation as following:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo __("accueil"); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo __("biographie"); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo __("agenda"); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo __("archives"); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><?php echo __("programmes"); ?></a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

I want that the hover append an arrow on the left of each navigation link. This is my css so far:

```
nav li a{
    color: #747474;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
nav li:hover:before{
    content: '> ';
    color: #fff;
}
```

This code is working, however I tried to add a transition to this arrow apparition to make it look smoother instead of appearing in a brutal manner. Unfortunately I failed and I cannot figure if this is even possible. There have other ways but since i'm facing this problem i would like to extend my knowledge and understand how to make this work.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><span>></span><a href="">aaa</a></li>
        <li><span>></span><a href="">bbb</a></li>
        <li><span>></span><a href="">ccc</a></li>
        <li><span>></span><a href="">ddd</a></li>
        <li><span>></span><a href="">eee</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav li a{
    color: #747474;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').find('span').hide();
    $('li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('span').fadeIn('slow');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('span').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DUyW2/)

Comment: Thanks Dh... but i'd rather use plain CSS than js for this. Also the effect is not really what i want.

Comment: Why you would not prefer to use js? and can you show me example link or demo what kind of effect you want. so that i can help you.

Comment: It's just a personal choice. For the example, click on "filtrer par catégorie" on the upper right in the menu. Then hover on the links and you'll see they are smoothly moving t the right. I want that same effet but in my case i want an arrow to appear only on hover. So at first it's a text link and on mouse hover an arrow pushes the link on the right to get its space. [link]http://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/cakephp